# Why it is possible to directly use Interface's method

Tags: java, interface, cloneable

I was reading about java and saw this code :

```
public class Person implements Cloneable{
    public Object Clone(){
        Object obj = null;
        try{
            obj = super.clone();
        }
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException ex){
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Since `Cloneable` is an Interface, how it is possible to access a method directly ?

Comment: It does not: it aims to access the `clone` method of `Object`...

Comment: FYI, cloneable is a tag interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `super.clone()` does **not redirect to the `Cloneable` interface**. `Cloneable` simply states that **the object is supposed to be "cloneable"**. It does [**not specifies any methods** (see the documentation)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

If you do not provide a superclass yourself, the **superclass of `Person` is `Object`**. `Object` has a [`Object clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) method itself (that raises an error).

So what happens here is that it calls the `clone()` of the superclass. If you do not provide a superclass (with `extends`), it will call the `clone()` of `Object` that raises an `CloneNotSupportedException`. Otherwise it will return `null` here.

In this case `super.clone()` will thus throw the `CloneNotSupportedException` since in the [specifications of `Object.clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()):

> The class `Object` does **not itself implement the interface `Cloneable`**, so calling the `clone` method on an object whose class is `Object` will result in **throwing an exception at run time**.

Answer (score 2):

`Cloneable` is a very special interface and does not have any methods defined. It is only used to indicate that this class can be cloned. If you wouldn't implement Cloneable the `super.clone()` would throw a `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Comment: Could you expand your answer further and tell me how could it throw an exception if a class is not implemented ?

Comment: You mean how the java framework checks if a class implements Cloneable in their Object.clone() method?

Comment: @findusl: no. By `implements Cloneable` you specify yourself that the object can be cloned. It is up to you to implement it. But you specify a "contract" that `clone()` will succeed.

Comment: @findusl Yes, that is what I am curious about
My feeling is that they check with `instanceof`

Comment: @SnuKies generally you can check if something implements an Interface with instanceof. However clone is a native method and since there is some magic going on here to copy all attributes of the class I would assume they use something more special

Answer (score 2):

> ***Since Cloneable is an Interface, ...how it is possible to access a method directly ?***

no you are not; Clonable interface is a [Tag interface](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=240) (has no methods), and the method Clone you are invoking comes from the Object class...

[image]

the clonable interface is just [empty](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Cloneable.java)